# Why wifi keeps dropping on all mobile devices except computers?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration, ieee802.1x

My wireless keeps dropping all the time, I've changed the password and ssid, nothing changed, i thought the problem from the router, i bought another router yesterday, it has worked fine around 6 hours, then the same problem came back, my computer connected with RG-45 cable and it works fine, but all mobile devices doesn't work, i took my laptop's friend, and i connected it with the Wi-Fi and it works fine, the problem is with mobile devices all of them doesn't work, do you have any ideas, if someone is jamming my wireless signals or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a WiFi analyzer app to make sure that the channel your router is on isn't overpopulated. If it is then switching to a less populated band will help.

Other than that I have had issues on my own where the 2.4GHz band in my house can reach everything but the 5GHz band will frequently cut out in areas. Devices will typically prioritize connecting to the 5GHz band rather than the 2.4GHz band so when your mobile device is getting spotty reception on that band it may just keep trying to reconnect to that band rather than use the lower speed band. The laptop likely has a better antenna so it isn't dropping that network. In my case I just had my phone forget the 5GHz network so it never tries to connect to that one.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've changed the WiFi channel, then everything has gone back to work